# List not updating inside "foreach" statement, returning empty list

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, foreach

I want to create a dataframe and iterate over each row using foreach, then foreach row, I make an object called `newSample` that is comprised of 3 String, and append this `newSample` into a list called `SampleList`. Finally, I will have a list of `newSample`, and use spark `toDF` statement to convert the list into a new dataframe.

Since List is immutable, I've also tried using ListBuffer instead of List

```scala
case class newSample(userID: String, featureName: String, featureValue: String)
var sampleList = List[newSample]()
// userFeatures is a list of strings, which are column names of df_short dataframe
// userID is a string, which is also the name a column of df_short    
   for (features <- userFeatures){
      val dfTemp = df_short.select(userID, features)
      dfTemp.foreach( Row =>{
        sampleList = newSample(Row.get(0).toString, features, Row.get(1).toString) :: sampleList
      })
      println(sampleList)
    }
```

```
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
List()
```

the printed `sampleList` should not be empty each time I print it out. But it is an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

`List` has a fancy `flatMap` function that let's you expand each element of the list into multiple and in the end collecting them all into a single list. This way you don't need to use anything mutable, be it `ListBuffer` or the foreach method.

```
    case class NewSample(userID: String, featureName: String, featureValue: String)
    val newSampleList = userFeatures.flatMap { feature =>
        df_short
          .select(userID, feature)
          .map(Row => NewSample(Row.get(0).toString, feature, Row.get(1).toString) :: sampleList)
          .collect()
          .toList
    }
```